# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused

Tags: python, flask, heroku, redis

Hi I understand that this question has been asked before but I haven't found a thread with the answer that works for me yet

I'm currently trying to add redis to flask app on heroku and I've been following the tutorial on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq#create-a-worker pretty much word for word and this is the code that I have

worker.py

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

I've got this in my Procfile

```
worker: python worker.py
```

And I've add methods to queue in my views.py file

```
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn

q = Queue(connection=conn)

@app.route('/view.html', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def view():
    df_one = q.enqueue(sqe, page_one)
    df_two = q.enqueue(sqe, page_two)
    return render_template('layouts/default.html',
                                   content=render_template('pages/view.html', one=json.dumps(df_one),two=json.dumps(df_two))
```

I also have Heroku Redis as my installed add-ons  and the dyno formation for 'worker python worker.py' is also on

The app can build on heroku but in my application logs there are these errors and I cannot access the pages with q.enqueue(...)

```
app[worker.1]: redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-infinite-26628 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.02 sample#load-avg-5m=0.075 sample#load-avg-15m=0.1 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664264kB sample#memory-free=12589900kB sample#memory-cached=938732kB sample#memory-redis=313968bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-infinite-26628 sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.23 sample#load-avg-5m=0.13 sample#load-avg-15m=0.115 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664264kB sample#memory-free=12591860kB sample#memory-cached=938736kB sample#memory-redis=313968bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
```

**Update:**
I've installed redistogo into my addons and there are no issues with connections anymore

Comment: So you are trying to run your code on heroku, yet want to  connect to an instance of redis on localhost?